SAS FSEDIT screen YES/NO
Want to limit responses on SAS FSEDIT screen control to yes/no.
Not converting ANYTHING via code.
There are two responses:
"YES"
"NO".
NOT 1 or 0 or anything else.
How do I limit the responses to those two options for a char variable?
Is it done in the variable on the data set, or done in code behind the control?
THX.
Response to below:
Richard,
These are very clear, concise instructions on a platform that is a throwback to the 90's.
In this form I've inherited, tasked to add one field with Y/N restrictions  "FLAG" in your example - there are a couple variables in the INIT section.  After clicking on option 3, I placed my variable there, just like the others above it,
"var=' '" (the new variable does not default to either "Y" or "N"),
placed your first snippet a few lines later, still in the INIT section.
Then went on to TERM, and placed the second snippet there.
After compile, I get an error "Variable XXXXX is defined but not used."
Did I not define it correctly in the INIT section? Or is that not where that happens?  Just looking thru the existing 1,300 lines of code, that appears to be what the other programmers did.
Or not.
Did try restricting the input with the alter table function below, and that does limit the input in that field.   Entering something other than "Y" "N", on the screen in question an error is thrown
"ERROR: ADD/UPDATE FAILED FOR DATA SET BECAUSE VALUES DO NOT COMPLY WITH INTEGRITY CONTRAINTS YESNO"
Pressing "F7" to save, results in an additional message:
"ERROR: DATA VALUE IS NOT VALID. PLEASE RENTER" - without telling you what values are allowed to be entered.
Our users would never figure that out.

Presume the variable name is FLAG is in data set MYDATA and you are using a custom screen named SASUSER.SCREENS.MYSCREEN.SCREEN
Issue command : FSEDIT MYDATA
Use menu Tools/Modify Screen, cursor to 3 Edit Program Statements and Compile and press Enter.
You can enter a program such as the following:
INIT:
  CONTROL LABEL ;
RETURN ;

FLAG:
  if FLAG not in ('YES' 'NO') then do ;
    rc = popmenu ({ 'YES', 'NO' }) ;
    if rc = 1 then FLAG='YES' ; else
    if rc = 2 then FLAG='NO' ;
  end ;
return ;

MAIN:
RETURN ;

TERM:
  if FLAG not in ('YES' 'NO') then do ;
    ERRORON FLAG ;
    _msg_ = 'FLAG must be YES or NO' ;
  end ;
RETURN ;

An alternative is to bypass the screen customization and install an integrity constraint on the column
proc sql ;
  alter table MYDATA add constraint YESNO CHECK (FLAG in ('YES'  'NO')) ;

